# ModuleNotFoundError even though module is in sys.path

Tags: python-3.x, linux, python-import, .so

I am puzzled by an apparent inconsistency here. It relates to the setproctitle module. Basically python3.6 can see it, and python3.8 can't.

I can demonstrate with a couple of simple command line demos running:

`python3.6 -c "import sys; print(sys.path); import setproctitle; print(setproctitle.__file__)"`

and

`python3.8 -c "import sys; print(sys.path); import setproctitle; print(setproctitle.__file__)"`

And here is the comparison:

```
$ python3.6 -c "import sys; print(sys.path); import setproctitle; print(setproctitle.__file__)"
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/bernd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setproctitle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
$ python3.8 -c "import sys; print(sys.path); import setproctitle; print(setproctitle.__file__)"
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/bernd/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setproctitle'
```

The salient observation being that setproctitle is found in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and that directory is in `sys.path` in both cases, for Python3.6 and Python3.8.

What can we conclude from that?

Given the loaded file named `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setproctitle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` has a suspicious 36m in its name it suggests that Python3.8 might be looking for `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setproctitle.cpython-38m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, but that would raise the ancillary question: How do we (canonically) get the 3.8 package of setproctitle?

I'll admit I tried sneakily:

`sudo ln /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setproctitle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setproctitle.cpython-38m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

and tried again but there's more to it than just the name. I have tried finding information on this on-line but am a little stuck having found nothing so far. If there are some simple summaries as to what is going on here and how to have seemingly binary libraries side by side for different Python versions, I'd be pleased for pointers.

My guesses are:

1. The .so fileis a binary file that contains links to a specific Python version
2. It would thus need to be rebuilt for Python3.8
3. It may be, given the youth of Python3.8 that it has not yet been rebuilt for distribution
4. It might be possible to rebuild it on the fly, perhaps with apt if one new the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an [extension module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES), which was built and tagged with a CPython 3.6 / Linux runtime. 
 Simply renaming that file is not a good idea and is unlikely to work. Even though that file is present on the `sys.path`, it will be ignored by a Python 3.8 runtime since the tag is not matching.

See [PEP 3149 -- ABI version tagged .so files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/).

To get a 3.8 version, you should build  - i.e. install from source - using a 3.8 runtime:

```
python3.8 -m pip install setproctitle
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully. It's installed in `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setproctitle.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` not in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` which is livable I guess, but if I run teh same build with sudo, it simply complains that `Requirement already satisfied: setproctitle in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` which is a puzzle of sorts, as it's sort of right, but only in the 3.6 sense and so 3.8 is refusing to put a build there. Hmmm...

Comment: Do not build with sudo. That’s every kind of wrong, there is never a reason to “sudo pip install”.

Comment: Really? So how do you provide a module like that to all users and system tools that rely on python 3.8? Indeed I have a web server on which I have a Django based website that I maintain and I'm about to move to Python 3.8 specifically so I can exploit a 3.8 feature I love, so how on an Ubuntu server do you ensure the 3.8 version of the module is in a system dir not a `~/.local` dir? Just curious.

Comment: But why do you think you need to run at system level in the first place? Django app doesn’t need to be installed for all users, and best practice will be to run as regular user, not root. If you just want to use privileged port then you can use iptables or similar and port forward 80.

Comment: A web server is a dedicated machine. I have no idea why you think the latest Python release should not be available system wide to system services so that a daemon running as www-data can use it without me having to log on as www-data to run it say, but manage it using my own account. The very reason we have sudo as a utility, to manage system level features logged in as a simple user.

Comment: The system Python env is often needed for functioning of the OS itself, and should be modified only with the system's official package manager (apt in your case, since you're running Ubuntu). Having sudo available to configure permissions for users does *not* imply that you should run services as root, or even install user code into root-owned subdirectories. It's not necessary, and there is no benefit - [but many downsides](https://hynek.me/articles/virtualenv-lives/)! If you need some libraries or apps newer than apt-get provides, it's best to use isolation of some sort (docker and/or venv)

Comment: Note that the package versions available in the official repos via apt-get have all been carefully chosen, tested, and sometimes even patched (e.g. for security vulnerabilities) in order to ensure they are compatible together without dependency conflicts. If you use `sudo pip install` instead of `sudo apt-get` then you're in danger of messing up all that, and may inadvertently break system services or daemons too. The libraries available via PyPI are not curated *at all* and you use at your own risk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205182/discussion-between-bernd-wechner-and-wim).